# Delegations are not Accounted for Abstains

Tags: democracy

I wanted to confirm a scenario as it was brought up by a community member and my Rust reading skills are not great haha.

So let's say there is a Vote in which the tally is:

```
Aye: 10
Nay: 5
Support: 10
```

Voter A has 5 tokens delegated to his name, and he decides to Abstain with his own 2 tokens, meaning his "voten power" (let's not account delegation conviction) is 7. It seems that delegation is not considered when voting Abstain tho, so the new tally is now:

```
Aye: 10
Nay: 5
Support: 12
```

Is this on purpose?

The relevant code is seen [here](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/frame/conviction-voting/src/lib.rs#L391-L433) - Where you can see that delegations are only considered inside of a `vote.as_standard` conditional. [Standard votes](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/frame/conviction-voting/src/vote.rs#L71-L114) are only `aye` or `nay`, as `abstain` is only an option for `SplitAbstain`. The `as_standard` function returns `true` only if the vote is `Standard`.

Anyways, wdyt?